# How can I reintialize my jquery datatable with new order property while keeping my previous other properties intact?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to change the order property of the jquery datatable after it has been initialized but donot want the destroy the previous object.
I tried to do `table.DataTable({retrieve: true, 'order' : [["1", "desc"]] }).clearPipeline().draw()` but this doesnot work.
Any idea in which way can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`column().order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().order()) to order the table by the selected column or [`columns().order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().order()) to order the table by the selected columns.

For example:

```
table.column(1).order('desc').draw();
```